# How to call function depending on the datatype of the variable the result is assigned to

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to C# and wondered if it is possible, to call a function based on the variable it is assigend to? I'm know i could overload the function and pass the variable as parameter, but I just wondered if this is possible.

Example, convert a value from a datarow to the datatype it is assigned to.

```
private int myint;
private string mystr;
private DateTime mydate;

myint = assign(datarow, "number");

// calls this
private int assign (DataRow r, string columnname)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(r[columnname]);
}

mystring = assign(datarow, "name");

// calls this
private string assign (DataRow r, string columnname)
{
     return Convert.ToString(r[columnname]);
}
```

Comment: That code isn't valid, you can't return values when the functions return type is `void`.

Comment: It's possible if you use `out` arguments instead of return types.

Comment: Further to @rene 's answer, the closest you will find to what you are looking for is generics: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx although as rene points out) is not possible.

Comment: sorry, corrected the code. It might be a duplicate, thank you for this. However, as a newbie i find them a bit hard to understand. But i will look further into the links posted.

Comment: You can create Generic function and handle the situation. Sample link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return type issues aside. You can not do this the function declarations collide. The compiler needs a unique signature for each method it compiles. It generates those signatures using the function name and the parameters. It does not care about return types.